# Unable to find cuDNN sample files to verify installation

Tags: nvidia

I downloaded cuDNN with `sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7_7.0.3.11-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb`

I then followed step 2.4 of this: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html

However, I don't see `/usr/src/cudnn_samples_v7` on my computer or in the deb file

I also followed this link, but don't see `include/cudnn.h` or `lib64/libcudnn*` anywhere: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326015/how-to-verify-cudnn-installation

how can I verify my cuDNN installation?

Comment: The link you posted says *"Install the code samples and the cuDNN Library User Guide, for example:
sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7-doc_7.0.3.11-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb"* - did you do so?

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions from the link that you posted:

1. do the instruction in 2.2 but also download the "cuDNN vX.0 Code Samples and User Guide (Deb)"
2. do the instruction in 2.3.2 step 4.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libcudnnX-doc_X.0.3.11-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb
   ```